# How to change list to list which has tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

To create list from sentence is what I want to do. Firstly, what I have done is coordinating this sentence,`data = "In many countries food manufacturers are required by"` to list like

```
lines = data.split(' ')
```

and got

```
['In','many','countries','food','manufacturers','are','required','by']
```

Then, I want to change this form to

```
([('In','many'),('countries','food'),('manufacturers','are'),('required','by')])
```

How should I do next ?
I would appreciate if you teach me in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 d=[(lines[i],lines[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(lines)-1,2)]
 print d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "In many countries food manufacturers are required by"
lines = data.split(' ')
print([(lines[i], lines[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(lines)-1, 2)])
```